# Select some item from cart to checkout

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, cart, mini-cart

I'm currently using Magento 2.3 and I'm trying to customize cart page. So basically I want to add checkbox to cart so I can select some item in my cart to proceed checkout. I have no lead to do this and I'm new on customizing Magento 2. Can you guys get me solutions please?

Here is the picture of the designer gave me.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution? Your requirement is similar to myntra website checkout. 

I have found some links of M1 hope you get some help from here:

1.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110136/checkout-only-1-item-from-magento-cart

2.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157563/magento-select-items-from-cart-before-place-order

Comment: I've read that but all of them are for Magento 1.9 while I'm using Magento 2